# Theorem 1.19 in Bruckner's Analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, baire-category, piecewise-continuity

Following is from Bruckner's Analysis book which I after lots of time try couldn't understand two parts :

[image]

My questions :

1- Even though I understood the proof of Theorem 1.18 completely, but still how the author concludes from that there must be $(J,E_n \subset J)$ such that $\text{Cl}(E_n)=J$?

2- In the last lines how it is concluded that $J \cap F(\epsilon) = \emptyset$? Elements of oscillation are defined for difference of the same $f$ at two points but the elements of $J$ are difference of two functions for one same point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The interval $I$ cannot be a countable sum of nowhere dense subsets, so at least one of the sets $E_n$ must be not-nowhere dense. This means (from the definition) that its closure has non-empty interior, so it contains an open interval $J$. In particular, ${\rm Cl}(E_n\cap J) = J$.
2. Assuming that the interval $J$ is open and $x\in J$ is fixed, we have $$|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/2,$$
   but also
   $$|f(y) - f_n(y)|<\epsilon/2$$
   whenever $y \in J$.
   If we take $\delta$ small enough, then $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset J$ and thus for every $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$
   $$|f(y)-f(x)| \leq |f(y) - f_n(y)| + |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(y) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 + c(\delta),$$
   where $c(\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta\to 0^+$, because $f_n$ is continuous. Thus, by letting $\delta\to 0^+$ we get that $x\notin F(\epsilon)$.

It is instructive to realize that in the definition of oscillation we can as well take the limit with $\delta\to 0^+$, because the quantity under $\inf$ decreases (as $\delta$ decreases) and is bounded from below.

Comment: Hi @ajr, may I have your email PLEASE?

Comment: Sorry, I have an exam in measure theory the following week and I am not good at it. I wanted to ask for your help and I would pay for your time. I couldn't write it here at first that. Thanks.